# ggplot & boxplot: is it possible draw a box plot with different variables?

Tags: r, variables, ggplot2, plot, boxplot

Is it possible to draw a bow plot with different variables, considering that these variable are in different datasets?

I'd like to draw a box for each one of them to make a comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by different variables.

You could do something like this.

```
ggplot()+
geom_boxplot(data=df_1, aes(x=x, y=y))+
geom_boxplot(data=df_2, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

This is not ideal better to combine the datasets with `rbind()` or `merge()`.

If it is a list you can use `do.call("rbind", df)` to combine all the elements of the list into one dataframe.

Comment: hi @jimmy_BOB and thank for the answer. I didn't know it was possible repeat `geom_boxplot()` multiple times inside ggplot specification. I'm going to try